# Flapped pronunciation of / l /

Tags: american-english, speech, phonetics

I've noticed lately the flapped realization of /l/ in AmE, as in the sentence "It's solo" from the song ***Solo* (Clean Bandit feat. Demi Lovato)**.

What are the causes behind this pronunciation?

Comment: Probably just artistic effect, I would guess. Tapped /l/ is not a usual feature of AmE, but anything goes when singing.

Comment: @Janus is your use of 'tap' instead of 'flap' overt?

Comment: @marcellothearcane Not really – I generally use them interchangeably and hadn’t even noticed I used a different term from the question. The distinction is rarely useful in my experience.

Comment: @Janus yes okay. Wikipedia is fairly vague on the difference.